# how to override an abstract method in a subclass?

Tags: java, overriding

I have to create subclasses for an abstract parent class which print out shapes, however whenever I try to create an object it keeps telling me that I cannot instantiate an abstract class, and when I remove the keyword `abstract` from my code that overrides, it says I can't do that either.

My code:

```
public class Rectangle extends VectorObject {
    protected int ID, x, y, xlnth, ylnth;
    protected int matrix[][];

    Rectangle(int id, int ax, int ay, int xlen, int ylen) {
        super(id, ax, ay);
        xlnth = xlen;
        ylnth = ylen;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void draw() {
        String [][] matrix = new String[20][20];
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                if (i == x) {
                    matrix[i][y] = "*";
                }
                if (j==y) {
                    matrix[i][y] = "*";
                }
                System.out.println(matrix[i][y]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Abstract parent class:

```
abstract class VectorObject {
    protected int id, x, y;

    VectorObject(int anId, int ax, int ay) {
        id = anId;
        x = ax;
        y = ay;
    }

    int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    void setNewCoords(int newx, int newy) {
        x = newx;
        y = newy;
    }

    public abstract void draw (char [][] matrix);
}
```

Comment: Don't worry too much about making mistakes now. Just learn and pay attention!

Comment: Your title and the error message you mention are unrelated. Please clarify.

Answer (score 9):

When you define an abstract method in a class, you are saying that subclasses of this object *MUST* implement them, unless they are another abstract class. So when you are extending the `VectorObject` with the `Rectange` class, you must implement a `draw` method with the same parameters.

Looking at the header of the function you provided in `VectorObject`:

`public abstract void draw ( char [][] matrix );`

Now lets look at the header of the function provided in `Rectange`:

`public void draw()`

These are not the same, so it is not considered an Override and there is an error, because you have not implemented the method `draw( char[][] matrix )`

The correct way to implement in `Rectange` would be:

```
public class Rectangle extends VectorObject {


   //... various methods and variable declarations.


    @Override
    public void draw( char[][] matrix ) {
       //... draw the Rectangle object
    }
}
```

When we add the `@Override` annotation, we are telling the compiler that we are overriding a parent classes method. You should always use this annotation when implementing a parent class method, as it will let you know if you somehow messed up the signature, and it is easier to understand by other developers.

Answer (score 2):

In order to **override** a method, they must have the matching signatures.

The abstract parent method has `char[][] matrix`; whereas the child method doesn't take any arguments. Thus you are **not** overriding.

In other words: **overriding** is more than just having two methods with the same name!

The easy thing that you should **always** do: put the @Override annotation on any method of which you think: I am overriding something here.

If you do that know, the compiler will tell you immediately that the Rectangle version of draw() doesn't override anything!

Answer (score -1):

Method signature is not the same. The parameters of the parent and child are different.
Try adding @Override annotation to child class method and it will show you the problems
@Override annotation ensure that all the mandatory conduct of overriding a method are followed. The method annotated would be checked against the parent method. If there are no method with matching signature it will show compilation errors.

In your case the parent abstract class method you need to override is 
 public abstract void draw (char [][] matrix)
whereas the child class method signature is 
 public void draw()
so the arguments mismatch

Comment: Try to answer it why and how not just how. Like why to add `@Override`. It will be helpful.